# MySQL to Oracle database query

Tags: mysql, database, oracle

I have created a MySQL database in which I have successfully executed the following query:

```
CREATE TABLE `Person` 
(
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `country` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

which created a table.

Now I want to create identical table in an Oracle c11 database. Server and database are ready to take queries, however when I use the same query from MySQL I get syntax errors. How should this query look in Oracle database? I use Oracle SQL Developer.

> Error starting at line : 1 in command - Error report - SQL Error: ORA-00907: brak prawego nawiasu 00907. 00000 - "missing right parenthesis"

Comment: What is the error you get?

Comment: Error starting at line : 1 in command - Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-00907: brak prawego nawiasu
00907. 00000 -  "missing right parenthesis"

Comment: Oracle and MYSQL are different animals _even though Oracle owns MYSQL now_. The syntax will be different. You need to read the Oracle Manual

Comment: Sorry questions like _Where can i find a solid tutorial how to use SQL in oracle databases_ are Off Topic [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: ok, removed that part, will read oracle manual, but in the meantime could you show me how this querry should look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what the query should look like

```
CREATE TABLE Person (
  id number NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY ,
  name varchar(20)  DEFAULT '' NOT NULL,
  country varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL
);
```

You need to create sequence and trigger for auto-increment or increase this manually in your code by calling sequence.nextval

Comment: Thank you, this is what i needed to know.